# Count de registros en cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp, relaciones, cakephp-3.x

Estoy intentando hacer un count() de registros entre dos tablas.

La primer tabla es Eventos y la segunda Es Moderadores
Existe una tabla intermedia EventosModeradores(es una relacion de muchos a muchos) que solo tiene las claves primarias evento_id y moderador_id.Además esta tabla intermedia no tiene modelo a nivel código

Lo que quiero es obtener la cantidad de eventos que tiene asignado un determinado usuario.

Por ejemplo:
Probe con algo de esto

```
$cantidad_eventos = $this->Eventos->Moderadores->find()->where(['Moderadores.moderador_id' => $current_user['id']])->count();
```

pero no obtengo resultado y me tira el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo supongo que es porque el cake no me reconoce la tabla intermedia al no exister el modelo en el código pero no sé como se podria hacer sin tener que crear el modelo.

Cómo podria obtener la cantidad de eventos de un usuario?

Answer (score 0):

**Solución:**
Lo solucione con un innerJoinWith , entonces la consulta queda así

```
$cantidad_eventos = $this->Eventos->find()->innerJoinWith('Moderadores')->where(['Moderadores.id' => $current_user['id']])->count();
```